# Temperature program

Tags: java, math

> The expected midday temperature in a town  is modeled by the equation
>
> ```
> T = 35 sin( (2π/365)(n-100) ) + 50
> ```
>
> where T is in Fahrenheit, and n is the number of days since the beginning of the year (Jan 1 == day 1). (The above equation is math; you will need to translate it into Java.)
>
> Write a program that asks the user for the day number n (an integer) and then writes out the expected temperature T (a double) for that day.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n; // number of days since the start of the year
    double t; // expected temperature for that day 
    
    
    // User enters the temperature at noon
    
    System.out.println("Enter the temperature at noon");
    n = scan.nextInt();
     
    
    // Compute expected temperature for this day. 
    
    t = 35 *Math.sin(Math.toRadians ( (2 * Math.PI ) / 365)*( n - 100 ) ) + 50;
    
    System.out.println(" The expected temperature for today is" + t);
```

This is what i wrote, but for some reasons my values do not make any sense.

Comment: sorry typing mistake in the question

Comment: Alright, then what are your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: the value for t when the user gives n.

Comment: No, I meant, when you say your "values do not make sense". Give **an example** of what doesn't make sense

Comment: Also, your input doesn't make sense. You don't "Enter the temperature at noon", you are entering how many days since the beginning of the year to **calculate** the temperature at noon.

Comment: for n=1 the t value should be close to 20. looking at the graph of the equation

Comment: 15.3, to be exact, but sure. And what are you getting?

Comment: that was for the second part of the problem. which i am not talking about in the question i asked here

Comment: @joe - Using this `t = 35 *Math.sin(( (2 * Math.PI ) / 365)*( n - 100 ) ) + 50;` gets you 15.3

Comment: @joe No, that equation in your question should come out to 15.3 degrees for `n=1`

Comment: computing the expected temperature at day n is the problem i'm having

Comment: @joe - Omit `Math.toRadians`

Comment: but if you then look at n=8 the value for t is not changing as much as it should.

Comment: @joe Probably because it's really cold in January. The temperature doesn't change that much in one week and [the sine function dips down](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=35*sin(+(2%CF%80%2F365)(n-100)+)+%2B+50+for+n%3D0..20)

Comment: @joe - Why are you converting to radians ? *pi degrees =
0.0548311356 rad* is making the difference.

Comment: you are right. i started plugging in more values and it makes more sense looking at day 100 and 200 as opposed to days 1 and 2. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason of your error:

the equation :

```
  t = 35 *Math.sin(Math.toRadians ( (2 * Math.PI ) / 365)*( n - 100 ) ) + 50;
```

is ok **BUT** Math.PI is actually a radian value...

so the hole argument of the sin function is taking a convertion of a radian to a radian, which is not correct...

## instead use:

```
t = 35 *Math.sin((2 * Math.PI ) / 365)*( n - 100 ) ) + 50;
```

Comment: I know, you have been following the comments very promptly.

Comment: @brso05 - His answer is what we have been discussing in the comments.

Comment: @LancePreston that is no reason to downvote. If you wanted to answer you should have answered. Please read the stackoverflow documentation on down voting - http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more readable (and runnable) version of your code with the correct math.

Notice that methods and reasonably named variables make your intentions more clear.

I also tend to find `System.out.printf` a cleaner version of printing values within strings.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  private static double expectedTemp(int n) {
      return 35 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI/365 * (n - 100)) + 50;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter the number of days since the beginning of the year (1-364): ");
      int n = scan.nextInt();

      double t = expectedTemp(n);
      System.out.printf("The expected temperature for today is %.02f.\n", t); 

      System.out.println("Enter the actual temperature at noon: ");
      double actual = scan.nextDouble(); 

      double tempDifference = actual - t; 
      System.out.printf("The difference between the predicted temperature and the actual temperature is %.02f.\n", tempDifference);

  }
}
```